# Why is it considered as bad to become ghost after death ? Do ghosts live a very miserable life?

Tags: mahabharata, puranas, tantra, afterlife, ghosts

It is being said that people who die by suicide or suffer violent death usually become ghosts .
So, why is becoming a ghost considered a bad thing ?

Is there more suffering in it ?

What things can  a ghost do ? Can he take revenge from people who wronged him or punish bad people in general ?

Can a ghost be captured and enslaved ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### `Why is it considered as bad to become a ghost after death ?`

The existence of ghosts as described in the scriptures is extremely horrid. It is considered bad on account of extreme sufferings a ghost is forced through.

### `Do ghosts live a very miserable life?`

Yes. Attainment of ghosthood has to be one of the worst forms of existence.

### `Is there more suffering in it ?`

Yes. A lot. Let's see.

#### Quoting from [Chapter 22](https://archive.org/details/GarudaPuranaEnglishMotilal3VolumesIn1/page/n849/mode/1up?view=theater), Preta Khaṇḍa (Dharma-kāṇḍa) of the Garuḍa Mahā-Purāṇa .

> The lord of the ghost's said :
>
> 33. O excellent brahmin, **our ghosthood is the outcome of our own misdeeds. We had been engaged in harassing others. Hence, we became
>     victims of foul death.**
> 34. **In this state of our ghosthood we are oppressed with hunger and thirst. We are unable to speak. We have lost our mental equilibrium.
>     We have lost consciousness too.**
> 35. We are Pisacas born of our own misdeeds. **We do not know the difference between one quarter and another. We are extremely
>     distressed. We do not know where we go.**
> 36. We have neither fathers nor mothers. This ghosthood is due to our own misdeeds. **We are extremely dejected and sorrowful because the
>     attack is all too sudden.**
>
> .....
>
> 48. & 49. Taking this illusory form, we wander over this wide region.
>     **We suffer from terrible distress. O Brahmin, you can judge from our deformed faces with protruding lips and twisted shapes. Our teeth are
>     long, our bodies huge, our faces crooked, due to our misdeeds.** Thus
>     I have told you how we turned ghosts.

.......

### `What do Ghosts Eat?`

> 53. ....... The ghosts said:
> 54. O brahmin, **our diet is extremely loathsome, despised by all living beings.** On hearing it from us you are sure to hate us. It is
>     so despicable.
> 55. **Mucous, secretions, feces, and urine together with other exudations, filth as well as the leavings of food constitute our
>     diet.**
> 56. **We eat, drink and revel in the house where people do not pay attention to cleanliness and where they scatter litter carelessly. We
>     haunt unclean beings as well.**
>
> .....
>
> 61. We lick up the urine mixed with semen from the vaginal passage of the widow having illicit intercourse with her paramour.
> 62. Dear friend, I am ashamed to tell you about the food we take. O pious brahmin, we lick up the menstrual blood from the generative
>     organ of a woman.

.........

### `What things can a ghost do ?`

> 57. We reside and enjoy in a house where there is no purity and where people do not observe truthfulness and restraint and where outcastes,
>     robbers, etc. join together and take meals.
> 58. **We take delight in haunting the house where no mantras are recited,** where no oblation is offered, where no homa is performed
>     and where people do not read the Vedas? regularly nor perform
>     religious rites.
> 59. We hover around the house where gods are not honored, where the householder is a vile wretch, without shame and decency, and where the
>     poor husband is controlled by his sturdy wife.
> 60. We enjoy gaiety in the house where covetousness, fury, somnolence, sorrow, fear, haughtiness, lethargy, quarrels, and deception reign
>     supreme.
>
> .....
>
> 63. O noble brahmin, preferring penance to riches, and engaged in performing the sacred rites', I ask you, out of frustration. Please
>     tell me the means of warding off ghosthood. **It is better to die a
>     hundred times than turn a ghost.**

......

### `Can a ghost take revenge from people who wronged him or punish bad people in general ?`

The text states that ghosts can cause severe mental/psychological distress and hallucinations. In terms of physical harm, the Purāṇa doesn't say anything worthwhile as such.

> [Chapter 23](https://archive.org/details/GarudaPuranaEnglishMotilal3VolumesIn1/page/n854/mode/1up?view=theater)
>
> 2. Being oppressed by hunger and thirst they enter their former home.
> 3. Though possessed of airy forms, they give signs to their sleeping descendents, O bird.
> 4. They visit the place where their sons, wives, and relatives sleep.
> 5. If a person dreams of a horse, an elephant, a bull, or a man with deformed face, **if a person awakened from sleep sees himself in the
>    opposite side of the bed, this is all due to the working of a ghost.**
>
> .....
>
> 10. **It is due to a ghost if one sees his wife, relative, son or husband as dead.**

....

### `Can a ghost be captured and enslaved ?`

No, this Purāṇa doesn't note anything worthwhile in this regard. However, I'm sure that this topic has been covered in some tantras, but I'm not gonna expound on that.

But yes, instead of capturing a ghost, the Garuḍa Purāṇa does give ways to attain freedom from its menace:-.

> 15. If in faith, one reads or hears this discourse, the ghosts disappear immediately from his vicinity.

---

Also, apparently, ghosts also have a designated name for themselves, as per the evil deeds that lead to their "ghosthood".

This has been explained in verses 38 to 47, of Chapter 22, by a ghost itself.

> 39. How can ghosts, the outcome of evil actions, have names? You may have some purpose in view in having these names. Please tell me.
>
> ......
>
> 41. While I was on earth as a man, I showed the hungry brahmins the exit door. Hence, my name is paryusita.
>
> ......
>
> 46. & 47. Thus acquiring our
>     ghosthood and names from our misdeeds we have got ourselves deformed
>     too. This Lekhaka is goat-mouthed; Rohaka is mountainfaced; Sighraga
>     is cow-faced; Sucimukha is needle-mouthed; I, Paryusita, am
>     crane-necked.