# Can only human beings become ghosts? What about other creatures?

Tags: afterlife, ghosts

There are various reasons for which someone may attain preta-hood (ghosts), as I discuss in [this answer](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/50569/17833).

I have only heard of human beings becoming ghosts, and there are several "reported-sightings" of such human-shaped ghostly figures.

**My question is - can the jiva of creatures ( like animals, birds, et al) or other beings, become ghosts post death, as per scriptures?**

I'm explicitly looking for references that either say, that only the jiva of humans can become ghosts, or any jiva occupying any body can become a ghost.

Comment: only the jivas of humans. the jivas that are in animals go immediately to their next birth.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, as per the Skanda Mahā-Purāṇa, only the jīvas in the human beings can become ghosts.

> [Chapter 50](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/the-skanda-purana/d/doc366037.html), Kaumārikā-khaṇḍa, Māheśvara-khaṇḍa, Skanda-purāṇa
>
> Verses 1.2.50.(72b to 74)
>
> मनुष्या एव गच्छंति यमलोकेन चापरे ॥ ७२.ख ॥
>
> > 72. (b). Only human beings go to the world of Yama and not others.
>
> ---
>
> **मरणानंतरं तेषां जंतूनां योनिपूरणम् । तथाहि प्रेता मनुजाः श्रूयंते
> नान्यजंतवः** ॥ ७३ ॥ धार्मिकः पूज्यते तत्र पापः पाशगलो भवेत् । धार्मिकश्च
> यथा याति तं मार्गं शृणु वच्मि ते ॥ ७४ ॥
>
> > 73. to 74. **It is after death that the creatures are allotted their different species of birth(?) Only men are heard (spoken of) as ghosts
> >     and not other creatures.** A virtuous man is honoured there and a sinner
> >     is tied with a noose round his neck. Listen to the path by which a
> >     virtuous man goes. I shall describe it to you.
>
> English Translation by G.V. Tagare

Therefore, we see, that as per the Skanda Purāṇa, only the jīva occupying the human body can attain preta-hood (become ghost).

The jīva in the body of any other being/creature, in general cannot become a ghost (preta), and unlike the human-jiva, neither other creatures visit the Yamaloka post their demise.